# How to find a street pattern that fits a specific edge on a map

Tags: image-processing, curated-data, geography

### Cross [post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1079942?p_p_auth=10F7S4lV) here

I have such funny pictures:
[image]

[image]

Very interesting,and you can get all of it by this code:

```
Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import[#], 
      "Byte"]]]] & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN3L5.png", 
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVnco.png", 
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzwJ5.png", 
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iderf.png"}
```

Well,since the *Mathematica* have all of the map data,I think it can do this,too.Suppose I have such picture:

[image]

We can get its edge very easily

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEQWP.jpg"];
Binarize[GradientFilter[img, 2], .5]
```

[image]

But how to hightlight it on map?

Comment: I believe your wording is a bit confusing. Would you like to overlay your image on the map, or would you like to find a street pattern that fits your image?

Comment: @ShamSays I suppose he want to find a street pattern similar to this image and highlight it.

Comment: @yode Interesting question -- it is very probable I will post an answer in the next few days.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Looking forward that. :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Will this reward insist on that moment?

Comment: @yode I am 60-70% through of having something working. The results might be not that good.

Comment: @AntonAntonov How about that work :)

Comment: @yode I have done some [ground work](http://i.imgur.com/YFvNeTG.png), but have been occupied with other things. Also, I am not sure my approach is going to produce great results. (But I might finish it this weekend anyway...)

Answer (score 5):

Wow, this  question was un-answered for a long time (4.7 years as of now)... In this year Wolfram Summer School 2021 (which I encourage you to apply for the next year), there was a project by [Junyao Chen called "Draw a Character on the Street Map"](https://education.wolfram.com/summer-school/alumni/2021/junyao-chen/), which I think in essence is what OP is asking. Here is a stab at drawing spelling WOLFRAM on a street map:

[image]

Not bad, and if room for improvements is needed here are the full library of the functions and code used (you can download the notebook by scrolling to the bottom and clicking "Make Your Own Copy" button):

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2314450

For fun demo, an interesting problem is a rotation of the shape on the streets grid, and here is the teaser of the result from the above post -- rotating letter "A":

[image]